# how to perform unit testing with route::resource Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

i want to perform unit testing on index page

this is my sample test code:

```
public function testBasicExample()
{
   $this->visit('/admin/newsmaster')->seePageIs('NewsMaster.index');
}
```

this is my route:

```
Route::resource('admin/newsmaster','FeedController',['only'  => ['index']]);
```

when i do **phpunit** in terminal i am getting message as:

FAILURES!

- Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
- what is the problem with this..??

Answer (score 0):

`seePageIs()` verifies if current url is the wanted one, after navigation, for example:

```
    $this->visit('/admin')
         ->click('Newsmaster')
         ->seePageIs('/admin/newsmaster');
```